# How to reload script tag

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I'm dynamically changing a `script` tag's src attribute using JavaScript.

Problem is, that I'd like to "undo" the previous JavaScript before re-executing it.
Any way to do this?

Thanks,

g3

Comment: Why do you add it in the first place? Ever thought about [loading it with ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) ?

Comment: I think you will find the answer here. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642205/how-to-force-a-script-reload-and-re-execute

Comment: The reason I add it is to add links to a navbar, however i want these links to change. (It's a packaged chrome app made with polymer)

Comment: Thanks @Sohel, I actually found that post before asking, but I was wondering if there was any easy-undo function. I'll do it a different way I guess ^^

Comment: Can you define "undo"? If all you did was instantiate a bunch of stuff, you could always just delete or otherwise overwrite that in-memory "stuff". Otherwise your solution potentially could be considerably more complex.

Comment: The first code creates a bunch of nodes and I want to get rid of them on the second run, but they share a class so I can just destroy them nonetheless ":)

Answer (score 0):

I can describe a method I used to achieve a partial undo in a project. Ugly, but might be useful. First, you may need to refactor your script to work from within an iframe, and/or wrap it in a `with` statement to give it easy access to some objects in the parent (don't even think of `with(opener)`; you'll want something more precise like `with({someObject: opener.someObject})`.

When your script runs, it can use the iframe's global scope and DOM freely. Then, instead of reloading the `<script>` tag, you overwrite the whole iframe, which will reset everything your script did inside the iframe.

Comment: CSP doesn't like Iframes unfortunately =/

Comment: Even an iframe whose content is document.written by the main page? that seems pretty safe to me…