# How to reload and re-execute an ad network script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm posting for the first time after having read through as many posts as I could find that seemed applicable. I'm an amateur dev so much of what I found here was over my head. If you have the time and willingness to look at my problem I'd really appreciate it.

I have a image gallery layout on my site. Each time a user views a new image in the gallery I want to re-execute/re-load an ad code on that page.

The ad code on the page looks like this:

```
<div class="slide-ads row" id="slide-ads-2" style='width: 300px; margin: 0px auto;'>
  <div class="ad-tag" data-ad-name="Rectangle2_newformat" data-ad-size="300x250" ></div>
  <script src="//tags-cdn.deployads.com/a/mindpause.co.js" async ></script>
  <script>(deployads = window.deployads || []).push({});</script>
</div>
```

On click I update the content and make a call to my `moveAds` function, which causes the ad code to re-execute (and thus to produce a new ad impression) through jQuery's `detach` and `appendTo` functions. This is the relevant code:

```
 $('.slide-next, .slide-start').on('click', function (e) {
   $current = $(this).closest('article');

   if ($current && $current.next().length > 0) {
     moveAds($current, $current.next());

     $current.hide();
     $current.next().show();
   }
});

function moveAds($src, $dest) {
  $ad2 = $src.find("#slide-ads-2");

  $elem = $ad2.detach();
  $elem.appendTo($dest.find(".slide-content"));
}
```

At exactly midnight EST on May 6th this approach stopped working, unexpectedly. The `detach` and `appendTo` functions simply stopped causing the ad codes to re-execute. I haven't been able to identify any code change, WordPress update, or any other change that might have caused this (nor has the ad network themselves).

I have two core questions:

1. Are there any obvious culprits that might have caused my approach to work one day and break the next (for ex: core jQuery updates)? What should I be looking for as I attempt to de-bug this?
2. In a single page framework in which content updates without full page refreshes, what is the fastest/most efficient way to re-execute ad code scripts like these? I read this thread but I wasn't sure if this approach was applicable for my use case:

Should I do something along the lines of what @kelly had [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642205/how-to-force-a-script-reload-and-re-execute)?

Comment: It would be helpful if you had some error messages to work with through the Console. Have you checked out the console for errors in your code?

Comment: Hi Philip - Thank you for the response. I have checked the console for errors but I'm not seeing any. The detach and appendTo functions are working (which I confirmed by outputting to the console the elements being attached and appended back). They just aren't causing the JS to re-execute, essentially.