# How to add HTML content at the beginning of the head tag in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am using the leaflet package for a Shiny application, and want to include a global switch (`<script>L_PREFER_CANVAS = true;</script>`) in the head tag BEFORE the leaflet.js script is called, but the `tags$head` function adds the content at the end of the tag after `<script src="leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>` so the switch doesn't work. (Source: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#global)

Is there any way to tell Shiny to add this switch to the beginning of the head tag?

Comment: Can probably try this to reload `leaflet.js` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642205/how-to-force-a-script-reload-and-re-execute