# Processing user input as javascript backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to build a "codewars" like clone. I want an HTML page with an input form that a client writes their solution in. When they hit submit, a post request is sent to my server with the string in the request body. I then want to evaluate that string as code on my server, run some test cases on it, and serve back the results.

`eval()` is of course the first solution that comes to mind, and since this is a personal project that doesn't need to be secure, it would be a great option. Only thing is, I'm have alot of trouble using `eval()` on the request body object property of interest. It will evaluate the function like expected, but I can't call that function later in my code - it's not saved in the execution context, and if I try to invoke it , I error out.

I came up with some hacky solutions, but they're not very reliable. Anyone know of a library that can take care of this? Or some other kind of method of sending their string to my server that will somehow work with eval?

Thank you.

Comment: _"Anyone know of a library that can take care of this?"_ Careful, such requests are off-topic for SO.  Perhaps instead you can share your attempts so that the community can then help to fix?

Comment: eval is evil. => somebody could takeover your server. *its just a personal project* => still not a reason to write unsecure code...

Comment: Mark, have you tried reloading the script like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642205/how-to-force-a-script-reload-and-re-execute

@Jonasw, If someone can take over your server by writing client-side js, then you have bigger problems...

Comment: @positlabs *client side* ??? Hes talking about evaling users js on server side...

Comment: Ah, ok i get it now. He should use docker or something :). There is also https://npm.runkit.com/karma but I'm not really familiar with it.