# How to reload external JavaScript library without reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I included the viostream api js library on the `head` of my project, so I can use the object `viostreamPlayer` in js file:

```
<head>
  ...
  <script src='https://publish.viostream.com/embed/api'></script>
</head>
```

I need to call `embed` function twice in js and without reloading page. However, the second time to use the `viostreamPlayer` would cause some problem.

Therefore, I would like to reload the api library before the second use. To make sure the `viostreamPlayer` object fresh and ready to use.

---

**More details:**

I use the `backbone.js` to load the video view in the page, and after another video view loaded by js, I should update the video content. That's why I need to call `embed` function twice, which is to load another video. The new video is successfully embedded, but all the event handler failed. Load page by js cannot reload the `head`.

The event handler is added by calling `on` method with `viostreamPlayer`:

`viostreamPlayer.on('play', function(){})`

But its out of work when I embedded the second video. That's why I am looking for the method to make sure the `viostreamPlayer` fresh before calling `embed` function.

Documentation: https://help.viostream.com/hc/en-us/articles/223291607-Embedding-and-using-the-Player-API

Cheers

**Update**

ViostreamPlayer has updated the api so the error is no longer existing.

Comment: "However, the second time to use the viostreamPlayer would cause some problem.". What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Hi @CharlieFish, I explained in the `More details`, the problem is all the event listeners cannot be set correctly and out of work

Comment: Have you tried contacting their support? Looks like a paid product. They should offer support. I'm not sure why you need to reload a script. Sounds more like a problem in their script.

Comment: @CharlieFish, yeah that's the other option, it's already under contact, but I am still trying to find any possible solution on my side.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure. I could be wrong but truly sounds like a problem in their script.

Comment: Yeps, it should be a design issue in their script. But based on the current script, the only way to do it reload the `script` in the `head`. You know that reloading the whole page didn't cause this problem, cos it reload the `head` part.

Comment: That's why I am looking for the way to reload the script library by js @CharlieFish

Comment: Yeah, and I just don't think that is possible. Could be wrong tho.

Comment: What about this solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642205/how-to-force-a-script-reload-and-re-execute

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you can use `$.getScript()` to reload.

Example:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    $.getScript("https://publish.viostream.com/embed/api?1")
        .done(function (script, textStatus) {
            console.log(textStatus);
        })
        .fail(function (jqxhr, settings, exception) {
            console.log.("Triggered ajaxError handler.");
        });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Arunesh Saxena. However, I found that `getScript` function cannot reload the script. For example, this js will include a object `viostreamPlayer`, and add a `delete viostreamPlayer` before `getScript` method, you could see it wouldn't create the object again