# how to refresh a specific js or css file by 2 second interval by jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to Reload a specific js or css file by 2 second of interval. can it be done by jQuery?

I have tried to php_loop to execute this, but it is added the script one more time. Therefore I have tried to setinterval() but it didnt respond.

Comment: what do you mean *exactly* by reload the js or css ? what is the purpose ? because at the moment i don't see any case where you would need to really *reload* one of them. And can you provide what you tried with `setInterval` ?

Comment: To be specific, I need to reload the google analytics code js to check something.

Comment: Giving an arbitrary reason without further explanation, is not what I would call “specific”. _“I need to reload the google analytics code js to check something”_ - most such libraries have some sort of initialization code, and it is often explicitly build-in into those, that they do not do the same work twice, if the script file was _accidentally_ embedded twice - so that could perhaps already be the reason, why what you tried with setInterval “didn’t work”. So please try and _actually_ be specific now - explain why you need this, and _show_ what you have tried so far. Go read [ask], please.

Comment: to be specific means, I need to refresh the google analytics code to show the user count.

Comment: Are you sure you want to reload the code and not only trigger an action based on the already loaded code?

Comment: I didn't get you. please explain once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reloading JavaScript or CSS should not be done without reloading the page.

- Reloading CSS would cause the Page to re render. (Not good if done every 2 seconds)
- Reloading JavaScript would cause a lot of problems with bindings, ...

I don't know what you are doing, but I would consider the "There is an update: Please refresh the page" alert box approach. (Like Gmail does for example)

If you still want to reload specific JavaScript or CSS, you can set the `src` attribute of the script/style tags with another version number (`file.js?v=randomnumber`).

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16573663/9150652) for example (You still need to add the version part, as said before, to fix caching issues):

```
function reload_js(src) {
    $('script[src="' + src + '"]').remove();
    $('<script>').attr('src', src).appendTo('head');
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your code. What if I need to reload the google analytics script only? because I need to show some user activity on a website.

Comment: @Kevin I dont know much about the google analytics script, but I guess it has a source right? If yes, take the approach from my answer. If no, give it an ID and sub `src` for `id` in the code from my answer.