# How to make react router Link load page like anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

on one of my components I have an external widget which requires a script tag and a special div element. Once the page loads the script inserts an iframe inside the div.

The issue I am having is that the widget only works when the page is loaded like a normal http page. This widget works when I use anchor tags however with Link it doesn't as there is no page load.

List component ----Link----> Property component

How can I achieve the same behavior but with Link?

App.js

```
    <Switch> 
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/list" exact component={List} />
        <Route path="/property/:id/:sleeps/:start/:end" exact component={Property} />
        <Route component={Error} />
    </Switch>
```

List.js

```
<Link to={`/property/${property.id}/${property.sleeps}/${property.start}/${property.end}`}>
    <img src={property.image} alt={property.name}/>
</Link>
```

Property.js

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    //function inserts script to body
    this.loadScript('https://widgetSite.co.uk/components/embed.js');
}

//inside render
<div
    data-calendar-key="widget key"
    data-calendar-property-id={this.propID}
    id="calendar-js">
    Your widget will appear here.
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried React portals? You can render children outside the DOM hierarchy using portals.

Comment: @Ray No I haven't heard of it, will look into now

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic example of React Portals.

```
Index.html

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <div id="my-widget"></div>
</body>
```

MyWidget Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const Widget = document.getElementById('my-widget');

class MyWidget extends Component {
  state = { openWidget: false };

 //functions to open close widget

  render() {
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(this.renderWidget(), Widget);
  }

  renderWidget() { /*add your widget elements*/ }
}

export default MyWidget;
```

You can now use the MyWidget component. Hope this helps.
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Ray, but I looked into it and unfortunately, I don't think this is what solves it. My issue is that when moving to the property page with Link the widget script is not sending it's GET requests.

Answer (score -1):

Try to implement something like this [How to force a script reload and re-execute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642205/how-to-force-a-script-reload-and-re-execute/9642359) in your loadScript function so your script will be force to re-load, re-execute and grab the right data-* every time componentDidMount is trigger. I hope this help