# Force load JS script on page

Tags: javascript

I have a third party JS script with class `Oreole` defined there. This script is located on a CDN server elsewhere. I have this reference in my HTML:

```
<script src="https://someothercdn.com/oreole.js"/>
```

Later in my page script code I have

```
let oreole = new Oreole
```

Sometimes the CDN fails with 504 or 502 and my code crashes. Usually, page reload helps. But how do I force script reload on my page?

```
if (typeof(Oreole) == "undefined") {
  //Do what exactly?
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force a script reload and re-execute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642205/how-to-force-a-script-reload-and-re-execute)

Comment: as a note, you should probably using webpack for such things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably host oreole.js somewhere else, but if you want to go with unreliable cdn, you can do something like this using jquery

```
$.getScript("https://someothercdn.com/oreole.js", function() {
 // do everything that needs oreole.js here
});
```

The page will keep running atleast, if oreole.js is not found or something happens only oreole part will crash